# Liferay - Getting localized name in javascript

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Consider the following code

```
function populateLayout(scopeGroupId){
    Liferay.Service.Portal.Layout.getLayouts(
        {
            groupId: scopeGroupId,
            privateLayout: false
        },
        function(layouts){
            for(var i=0;i<layouts.length;i++){
                var layout = layouts[i];
                alert(layout.name);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see from the above Liferay's JSON service API to get all the layouts. I particularly need layout name to populate in a select box. I know that the name is stored as xml string to support different locales. I was wondering if there is javascript api to get just the name of the  layout using this xml string and language id. There is a java api for doing the same as below. I need equivalent javascript API if any.

```
layout.getName(locale)
```

or

```
LocalizationUtil.getLocalization(String xml, String languageId)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no such utility on Liferay's JavaScript libs.

Most of the times people need to do it in Liferay, they just parse the content in the server side and send the parsed content to the client. Frequently, the client only needs the value in the default locale; if it needs more, the developer finds a way to write it in HTML itself. See e.g. [the `input-localized` tag](http://tinyurl.com/klwohc6) where the developer writes the code to create a JS object directly in the output.

This makes sense: parsing XML is resource-costly so one would rather avoid it on client-side JavaScript. It may be even that there is a utility to do that in Liferay but I'd propose an alternative approach: just ask what you want to use in your JavaScript and write it in the HTML. For example, instead of writing the following *JavaScript* code

```
var names = Liferay.Util.Localization.nonExistentMethodToGetLocaleMap(layout.name);
for (var locale : names) {
     alert(names[locale]);
}
```

decide *in server-side* which layouts to display and write the following *JSP* code:

```
Map<Locale, String> names = layout.getNameMap();

<script>
    <% for (String name : names.values()) { %>
    alert('<%= name %>');
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Not much clear, I agree, but rather efficient.